# How to edit my Firebase rules for a React Native App in a store so that the data is sent without being authenticated?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a mobile application with the Firebase database.
In the application, the customer orders products through the mobile App, and for now I have not added the need to register to order.
The store receives the orders in the web panel and answers the customer.
Well, I created some default rules, but Google has already told me that my rules are insecure and I must change them.

```
// In this way the orders arrive from the mobile App to the database, but it is not secure

service cloud.firestore {
  match / databases / {database} / documents {
    match / {document = **} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have changed them:

```
// In this way the orders made from the App do not reach the database
service cloud.firestore {
  match / databases / {database} / documents {
    match / {document = **} {
      allow read: if true
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.data.author_uid
    }
  }
}
```

I've read the Firebase documentation and answers on this site on the topic of Firebase rules, but I can't figure out the correct way to write my rules.

With the rules configured in the first way, the application works, but they are not secure.

When I change them to the second option, the mobile application does not send the orders to the web panel of the store, since it is not registered.

How should I configure my rules so that they are safe and at the same time the user can place orders?

**I edit the question**
IMPORTANT:
My application does not have an authentication method, in the App you do not have to register to place an order

I must say that the application does not have authentication, this is working on it, but for now, anyone can place an order without being registered, since the application does not have this function at the moment

In the database I only have two collections: products (the products of the store)
orders (orders made from the app)

The App consults the database as follows:

Order progress:

```
const ProgresoPedido = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const { idpedido, total } = useContext(PedidoContext)

  const [tiempo, guardarTiempo] = useState(0)
  const [completado, guardarCompletado] = useState(false)
  const [totalBD, setTotal] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    const obtenerProducto = () => {
      firebase.db.collection('ordenes')
        .doc(idpedido)
        .onSnapshot(function (doc) {
          guardarTiempo(doc.data().tiempoentrega)
          guardarCompletado(doc.data().completado)
          setTotal(doc.data().total)
        })
    }
    obtenerProducto()
  }, [])
```

And this is the product query:

```
const FirebaseState = props => {

  // Crear state inicial
  const initialState = {
    menu: []
  }

  // useReducer with dispatch to execute functions

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(FirebaseReducer, initialState)

  // Function that is executed to bring the products

  const obtenerProductos = () => {

    // Consultar Firebase
    firebase.db
      .collection('productos')
      .where('existencia', '==', true) // TRAE SOLO LAS EXISTENCIAS PLATOS QUE HAY
      .onSnapshot(manejarSnapshot)

    function manejarSnapshot(snapshot) {
      let platos = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
        return {
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }
      })
       
      //Sort by category with lodash
      platos = _.sortBy(platos, 'categoria')

      //console.log(platos)
      // We have the results from the database
      dispatch({
        type: OBTENER_PRODUCTOS_EXITO,
        payload: platos
      })

    }
  }
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your Firestore db

Comment: It's saying because firebase don't Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions to use this rule set in production;

Comment: You should only allow user to read/ write until they are authenticated.

Comment: You should replace above with this one -  service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

These rules are insecure because your are allowing any authenticated user to read/write any part of your database. `match /{document=**}` is a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) which applies the rule to all documents and all it's sub-documents.

Assuming you have a users collection and an orders collection like this:

```
users -> {userId}
(col)     (doc)

orders -> {orderId}
(col)      (doc)
```

You can add these rules:

```
// In this way the orders made from the App do not reach the database
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid === userId;
    }
    
    match /orders/{orderId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid === resource.data.userId;
    }
  }
}
```

These rules will allow the user who created that order only to read/write the order. You would have to store the userId in a field in order document (`author_id` in your example).

> When I change them to the second option, the mobile application does not send the orders to the web panel of the store, since it is not registered.

That's because the rules expect the user to be logged in via Firebase Auth.

> I have not added the need to register to order.

That's where [Firebase Anonymous Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) comes handy. You can create a new anonymous user which does not require any credentials from user but will create a user in Firebase Auth with an UID which can be used in Firestore document and securely store user's orders.

When a user is about to finalize an order, you can [convert anonymous account to a permanent account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account). This is highly recommended because if the user logs out of their anonymous account by any means including explicit sign out or uninstalling app, the same account (with that UID) can never be recovered.

---

Do note that you can also structure the database as shown below:

```
user -> {userId} -> orders -> {orderId}
```

This way you might not need to store userId as a field in every order document.

Comment: @Estudiante As stated in updated question you don't use Auth currently, but I'd recommend using the Anonymous auth as mentioned in my answer to securely store all orders and user info. The app flow on user side will not change (i.e. user won't have to do anything), it's just how you are storing the data and auth state. And to use Firestore rules securely you do need Firebase auth so store some identifiers about users in another collection.

Comment: @Estudiante please can you ask that in English?

Comment: I have added its rules and the app breaks does not work console.error: **Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: Uncaught Error in snapshot listener: FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions** . It also doesn't allow me to use the "===" operator.

Comment: It is `==` not `===`. Also did you implement anonymous auth in your app and logged in via that ?

Comment: I have enabled the mode, but the app still does not work.I must edit the code that you wrote, to add the commands and that is: idpedido,.But I don't know how to edit the code that you have written, to adapt it to my database, And fix the error it shows now

Comment: @Estudiante not just enable mode, you need to implement it via code. See the link in my answer.

Comment: I'm reading the documentation, but as I said, I don't know where I should implement this code and I don't know if I should also edit the code that you wrote in the answer or is it the exact code that I should put in my rules. I am a bit puzzled. I will read the documentation over and over again until I find the solution

Comment: @Estudiante that sounds a totally new question "How to implement Anonymous auth in React Native" tbh. You just need to make sure that user is logged in. You can do so by using `onAuthStateChanged` in Firebase auth.

Comment: Is there anything that's still unclear about original question ?

Comment: Ok, I'll ask a new question to see how to implement anonymous authentication. I think you mean that. If I can solve the problem, I will give your answer as good, for the moment, you must understand that I cannot accept the answer, since my application does not work. Thank you for the effort you are making to help me.

Comment: Understandable, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxmoromkxY4) might be useful

Comment: I have tried your system and it does not work for me. In the App it is not necessary to register to place an order. It does not have an authentication method or registration method. Even with these rules, the store owner, who is registered by mail in the same database, cannot add products to the database from the App Web panel. I'll keep looking for a solution or maybe edit the question to better explain the problem

Comment: @Estudiante so you are trying to secure database with security rules _without authentication_?

Comment: The only user that is authenticated is the owner of the store, who manages the products and orders from the Web panel. To order now it is not necessary. Do you see it as a problem? This being the case, you would need to implement a function that forces the user to register to place an order. I have to add a login system, and my experience is still little to do this. You should look up information to learn how to do this. The user could enter the App, but the moment he wants to place an order, he must register. How does this look to you? Would it be difficult to implement this in my App?

Answer (score 1):

It's is recommended to allow read/write access to your users until they are authenticated. If you openly allow your users then It will show you warnings.

Replace your rules with the given one:

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This one is still insecure and will keep showing the warning as it allows any authenticated users to read/update/delete anything in the database

Comment: I think you are right buddy but at least it is more secure than open rules.. Thanks for extra layer of knowledge.